# У меня ССП с общим членом?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Но в отличие от крошечных подземных захоронений, парадные усыпальницы
>   создавались на протяжении жизни заказчика, и зачастую он имел
>   возможность не просто высказывать пожелания, но наблюдать за работами
>   и вносить в их исполнение коррективы.

С запятой бы разобраться перед "и зачастую".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-моему, запятая на месте. Не вижу общего члена. Он "имел возможность" не "в отличие от захоронений", а потому, что усыпальницы созадавались на протяжении его жизни.